# Moodle - After upgrading from 2.6 to 2.8 my images do not appear

Tags: image, upgrade, moodle

I have upgraded my site from 2.6.2 to 2.8.1+. In doing so, I now have a problem viewing the images which I had previously uploaded to my site (approximately 400 images).  The image description (i.e. an alt) appears instead of the image.  When performing the upgrade I following the instructions that were given on the Moodle site. This was to backup to Moodle folder in public.html and then replace it with the new version. At first some files failed to transfer but I was able to successfully upload those with a second attempt. I then move the config.php file over to the new folder as instructed.

I have asked both my hosting provider and the Moodle community forums but no solution has been found.  Could you advise me how to fix this problem?

Having switched to a debugger setting I can see a log of errors but being new at this, I do not know what they mean or how to fix it.

The error list is as follows (there seem to be repeats, not sure if this is relevant):

```
line 116 of /blocks/moodleblock.class.php: call to block_navbuttons->init()
line 1656 of /lib/blocklib.php: call to block_base->__construct()
line 66 of /lib/classes/plugininfo/block.php: call to block_instance()
line 133 of /lib/classes/plugininfo/base.php: call to core\plugininfo\block->init_display_name()

line 90 of /lib/classes/plugininfo/base.php: call to core\plugininfo\base::make_plugin_instance()
line 369 of /lib/classes/plugin_manager.php: call to core\plugininfo\base::get_plugins()
line 54 of /admin/settings/plugins.php: call to core_plugin_manager->get_plugins_of_type()
line 6656 of /lib/adminlib.php: call to require()
line 19 of /admin/settings.php: call to admin_get_root()
Invalid get_string() identifier: 'navbuttons' or component 'block_navbuttons'. Perhaps you are missing $string['navbuttons'] = ''; in /home/fungaled/public_html/moodle/blocks/navbuttons/lang/en/block_navbuttons.php?
line 348 of /lib/classes/string_manager_standard.php: call to debugging()
line 6957 of /lib/moodlelib.php: call to core_string_manager_standard->get_string()
line 20 of /blocks/navbuttons/block_navbuttons.php: call to get_string()
line 116 of /blocks/moodleblock.class.php: call to block_navbuttons->init()
line 1656 of /lib/blocklib.php: call to block_base->__construct()
line 90 of /lib/classes/plugininfo/block.php: call to block_instance()
line 56 of /admin/settings/plugins.php: call to core\plugininfo\block->load_settings()
line 6656 of /lib/adminlib.php: call to require()
line 19 of /admin/settings.php: call to admin_get_root()
Invalid get_string() identifier: 'activityalways' or component 'block_navbuttons'. Perhaps you are missing $string['activityalways'] = ''; in /home/fungaled/public_html/moodle/blocks/navbuttons/lang/en/block_navbuttons.php?
line 348 of /lib/classes/string_manager_standard.php: call to debugging()
line 6957 of /lib/moodlelib.php: call to core_string_manager_standard->get_string()
line 24 of /blocks/navbuttons/settings.php: call to get_string()
line 99 of /lib/classes/plugininfo/block.php: call to include()
line 56 of /admin/settings/plugins.php: call to core\plugininfo\block->load_settings()
line 6656 of /lib/adminlib.php: call to require()
line 19 of /admin/settings.php: call to admin_get_root()
Invalid get_string() identifier: 'activitycomplete' or component 'block_navbuttons'. Perhaps you are missing $string['activitycomplete'] = ''; in /home/fungaled/public_html/moodle/blocks/navbuttons/lang/en/block_navbuttons.php?
line 348 of /lib/classes/string_manager_standard.php: call to debugging()
line 6957 of /lib/moodlelib.php: call to core_string_manager_standard->get_string()
line 25 of /blocks/navbuttons/settings.php: call to get_string()
line 99 of /lib/classes/plugininfo/block.php: call to include()
line 56 of /admin/settings/plugins.php: call to core\plugininfo\block->load_settings()
line 6656 of /lib/adminlib.php: call to require()
line 19 of /admin/settings.php: call to admin_get_root()
Invalid get_string() identifier: 'activitynever' or component 'block_navbuttons'. Perhaps you are missing $string['activitynever'] = ''; in /home/fungaled/public_html/moodle/blocks/navbuttons/lang/en/block_navbuttons.php?
line 348 of /lib/classes/string_manager_standard.php: call to debugging()
line 6957 of /lib/moodlelib.php: call to core_string_manager_standard->get_string()
line 26 of /blocks/navbuttons/settings.php: call to get_string()
line 99 of /lib/classes/plugininfo/block.php: call to include()
line 56 of /admin/settings/plugins.php: call to core\plugininfo\block->load_settings()
line 6656 of /lib/adminlib.php: call to require()
line 19 of /admin/settings.php: call to admin_get_root()
Invalid get_string() identifier: 'activitycustomassignment' or component 'block_navbuttons'. Perhaps you are missing $string['activitycustomassignment'] = ''; in /home/fungaled/public_html/moodle/blocks/navbuttons/lang/en/block_navbuttons.php?
line 348 of /lib/classes/string_manager_standard.php: call to debugging()
line 6957 of /lib/moodlelib.php: call to core_string_manager_standard->get_string()
line 35 of /blocks/navbuttons/settings.php: call to get_string()
line 99 of /lib/classes/plugininfo/block.php: call to include()
line 56 of /admin/settings/plugins.php: call to core\plugininfo\block->load_settings()
line 6656 of /lib/adminlib.php: call to require()
line 19 of /admin/settings.php: call to admin_get_root()
Invalid get_string() identifier: 'activitycustomchoice' or component 'block_navbuttons'. Perhaps you are missing $string['activitycustomchoice'] = ''; in /home/fungaled/public_html/moodle/blocks/navbuttons/lang/en/block_navbuttons.php?
line 348 of /lib/classes/string_manager_standard.php: call to debugging()
line 6957 of /lib/moodlelib.php: call to core_string_manager_standard->get_string()
line 35 of /blocks/navbuttons/settings.php: call to get_string()
line 99 of /lib/classes/plugininfo/block.php: call to include()
line 56 of /admin/settings/plugins.php: call to core\plugininfo\block->load_settings()
line 6656 of /lib/adminlib.php: call to require()
line 19 of /admin/settings.php: call to admin_get_root()
Invalid get_string() identifier: 'activitycustomquiz' or component 'block_navbuttons'. Perhaps you are missing $string['activitycustomquiz'] = ''; in /home/fungaled/public_html/moodle/blocks/navbuttons/lang/en/block_navbuttons.php?
line 348 of /lib/classes/string_manager_standard.php: call to debugging()
line 6957 of /lib/moodlelib.php: call to core_string_manager_standard->get_string()
line 35 of /blocks/navbuttons/settings.php: call to get_string()
line 99 of /lib/classes/plugininfo/block.php: call to include()
line 56 of /admin/settings/plugins.php: call to core\plugininfo\block->load_settings()
line 6656 of /lib/adminlib.php: call to require()
line 19 of /admin/settings.php: call to admin_get_root()
Invalid get_string() identifier: 'activityreadydesc' or component 'block_navbuttons'. Perhaps you are missing $string['activityreadydesc'] = ''; in /home/fungaled/public_html/moodle/blocks/navbuttons/lang/en/block_navbuttons.php?
line 348 of /lib/classes/string_manager_standard.php: call to debugging()
line 6957 of /lib/moodlelib.php: call to core_string_manager_standard->get_string()
line 40 of /blocks/navbuttons/settings.php: call to get_string()
line 99 of /lib/classes/plugininfo/block.php: call to include()
line 56 of /admin/settings/plugins.php: call to core\plugininfo\block->load_settings()
line 6656 of /lib/adminlib.php: call to require()
line 19 of /admin/settings.php: call to admin_get_root()
```

Comment: These errors are minor warning about a language strings you have in block plugin 'navbuttons' that are missing. These errors are not the cause of your issue. Upgrade any third plugins you have to version compatible with Moodle 2.8 and purge moodle cache. This may help your to fix the issue.

Comment: @satrun77 Thank you. I have upgraded any plugins and purged the cache. Unfortunately this has had no change. In addition to the above detail. I am able to upload images and have them appear in 2.8.1+, only those uploaded with the old version of 2.6.2 that do not appear. I have over 400 images so replacing each one is not desirable.

Comment: are you able to provide a link to download the entire log? or turn debugging to developer level and send me the output of the image url.

One of the errors above states that the language string 'activitycustomquiz' does not exists in the language file of the  plugin, but based on the plugin source code it exists: https://github.com/davosmith/moodle-navbuttons/blob/master/lang/en/block_navbuttons.php#L24

It is possible that Moodle failed to purge the cache.

Comment: After looking closely, it seems Moodle refused to automatically copy over new files. I have now reduced the errors to: 

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$response_editor in /home/fungaled/public_html/moodle/mod/lesson/locallib.php on line 2275

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$response_editor in /home/fungaled/public_html/moodle/mod/lesson/locallib.php on line 2275

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$response_editor in /home/fungaled/public_html/moodle/mod/lesson/locallib.php on line 2275

Comment: I still have no look with the images appearing either. The image URL for one example is: 

http://www.fungaleducation.net/moodle/pluginfile.php/292/mod_lesson/page_contents/155/%5BM3-223%5D%20Disseminated%20aspergillosis%20Figure%206_30.jpg

However nothing loads when i go to this link (you probably won't be able to access it unless I displayed login details)

Comment: @satrun77 sorry, and this error
able "navbuttons" does not exist

More information about this error

Debug info: 
Error code: ddltablenotexist
Stack trace:
line 585 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: dml_exception thrown
line 1426 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->where_clause()
line 144 of /blocks/navbuttons/edit.php: call to moodle_database->get_record()

Comment: You can ignore the first error message "Notice: Undefined property".  Its  only visible when debugging is turned on.

The second error message is most likely the cause of your issue. It indicates that the database table "navbuttons" does not exists. You will need to copy the table from your old database site to the new one. Also, make sure the structure of the table matches the table definition in ./blocks/navbuttons/db/install.xml

Comment: Did you copy the moodledata folder before upgrading?

Comment: @RussellEngland  - unfortunately I did not. I performed the upgrade 4 weeks ago and have since added content so could not revert back anyway.

Comment: ah... that will be why the images are missing then.. Not sure what you can do about that now. You could try copying moodledata but not overwrite anything - I've no idea if that will work though.

Comment: @RussellEngland - Sorry I don't know what I read. I performed a backup of moodledata, but this can not be put back into a new version of moodle (I have tried) due to the core code being newer than the database.The files are there, I can go into moodledata and there is content. The 'title' of the image appears on the site, just not the actual image.